# how to create a like and dislike function on python flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So i been trying to make a like function for my q&a website. however, i'm stuck on database relations part of the models.py. I'm getting an error that says

"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.posts - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table."

This is my code for the user and post class

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column("title", db.String(200))
    text = db.Column("text", db.String(100))
    date = db.Column("date", db.String(50))
    #Create Foreign Key
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship("Comment", backref="post", cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy=True)
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    likes = db.relationship('PostLike', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
```

and my user class

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column("first_name", db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column("last_name", db.String(100))
    email = db.Column("email", db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="user", lazy=True)
    comments = db.relationship("Comment", backref="user", lazy=True)

    liked = db.relationship(
        'PostLike',
        foreign_keys='PostLike.user_id',
        backref='user', lazy='dynamic'
    )

    def like_post(self, post):
        if not self.has_liked_post(post):
            like = PostLike(user_id=self.id, post_id=post.id)
            db.session.add(like)

    def unlike_post(self, post):
        if self.has_liked_post(post):
            PostLike.query.filter_by(
                user_id=self.id,
                post_id=post.id).delete()

    def has_liked_post(self, post):
        return PostLike.query.filter(
            PostLike.user_id == self.id,
            PostLike.post_id == post.id).count() > 0
```

my postlike class in the models.py

```
class PostLike(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post_like'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

my flask file for like_action function

```
@app.route('/like/<int:post_id>/<action>')
def like_action(post_id, action):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first_or_404()
    if action == 'like':
        session['user_id'].like_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    if action == 'unlike':
        session['user_id'].unlike_post(post)
        db.session.commit()
    return redirect(request.referrer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two foreign keys pointing to User on Post:

```py
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

so, your User doesn't know where to point

```py
posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="user", lazy=True)
```

Have something like `recipient = db.relationship (..)` and `author = db.relationship (..)` in User model, and make `posts = db.relationship("Post", back_populates="author", lazy=True)`.